# How to add another C file in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

so my teacher wants the function prototypes and typedefs for my project stored in a separate .c file.
so main.c has the stuff to do, another.c has the protypes and typedefs, and another.h has the declarations.

how can i do this?  i am using GNU GCC compiler because it seems like this is a compiler specific issue.  i was trying gcc another.c but the compiler doesn't recognize the gcc so i think I'm doing it wrong.

i feel so dense.... i have the entire project working good but everything that's supposed to be in the another.c is in the another.h....

thanks

Comment: You mean `#include`? Sounds like you should listen more in class!

Comment: she never covered it in class, and the TA for lab refuses to help me because i didn't want to learn how to code in linux.  i tried #include another.c without working and i tried the gcc another.c

Comment: so why do you start sentences with "so"? so why don't you capitalize the first letter of sentences and "I"? so please treat us at least as well as you would a potential employer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main.c will look something like this:

```
// bring in the prototypes and typedefs defined in 'another' 
#include "another.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int some_value = 1;

    // call a function that is implemented in 'another' 
    some_another_function(some_value);
    some_another_function1(some_value);
    return 1;        
}
```

The another.h should contain the typedefs and function prototypes of the functions found in another.c file:

```
// add your typdefs here

// all the prototypes of public functions found in another.c file
some_another_function(int some_value);
some_another_function1(int some_value);
```

The another.c should contain the function implementations of all the function prototypes found in another.h:

```
// the implementation of the some_another_function
void some_another_function(int some_value)
{
    //....
}

// the implementation of the some_another_function1
void some_another_function1(int some_value)
{
    //....
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, i guess i just had everything backwards.

Comment: As a general rule remember that the c file should contain code that runs and the header file contains the definitions of that code. So the code that runs (i.e. code that you can put a break point on) should be found in the c file and not the h file (in most case). Also you include h files and you compile and link the c files.