# Project won't link in Codeblocks IDE

Tags: c, codeblocks, linker-errors

I am using another C and header file in my project but when I compile it in codeblocks it gives "undefined reference" error for the functions in other c file. But when I use below command in command prompt it works fine:

> gcc -o executable lodepng.c main.c

I believe it is a problem with linking two C files but I don't know much about this topic. I want to work on an IDE, Is there any way?

Comment: All IDEs work similarly. You need to create a 'project', and add both files to it.

Comment: Please show your Code::Blocks project file. Please show the compile and link command, and the error. Also see [How to add another C file in Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22950529/608639). Maybe related [How to compile and run a C file in CodeBlocks which is outside a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46386997/608639)

Comment: what build system are you using.

Answer (score -1):

You can work with vs by adding emty cpp file and save it as c file ..
The header file work fine with c lang....
Also you can define the codeblocks ide compailer ..
here a link..
https://youtu.be/rpipDcG8GMg

Comment: First thanks for the answer. See, when I do the same thing in that video I get the error: "undefined reference to multiplication" what could be the reason for that?